# Having difficulty in looping partNumber XSLT being applied shown below

Tags: xslt-2.0

Sample SOAP Input XML  Given below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                     <s:Body>  
                <PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse xmlns="http://cdx.dealerbuilt.com/Api/0.99/">
                   <PullCustomerPartsPricingResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.BaseApi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <a:CustomerPart>
                          <a:Placement>
                            <a:GroupId>10</a:GroupId>                                    
                          </a:Placement>
                         <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.Models.Parts">
                            <b:Description>PAD SET, RR.</b:Description>                            
                            <b:PartNumber>31500SB2100M</b:PartNumber>
                            <b:PartNumberFormatted>31500-SB2-100M</b:PartNumberFormatted> 
                        </a:Attributes>                 
                      </a:CustomerPart>
                      <a:CustomerPart>
                         <a:Placement>
                            <a:GroupId>10</a:GroupId> 
                         </a:Placement>
                          <a:Attributes xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DealerBuilt.Models.Parts">
                            <b:Description>Kite  SET, RR.</b:Description>                           
                            <b:PartNumber>60211T7J305ZZ</b:PartNumber>                            
                        </a:Attributes> 
                       </a:CustomerPart>
                  </PullCustomerPartsPricingResult>
               </PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse>
             </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

XSLT Code being applied Shown below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root xmlns="http://www.dataprint.com/global/3.0/rest/">
       <xsl:for-each  select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']/*[local-name()='CustomerPart']">

                    <partDetail>    
                      <partNumber>
                                <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']/*[local-name()='CustomerPart']/*[local-name()='Attributes'] /*[local-name()='PartNumber']" />
                       </partNumber>        
                      <partDescription>
                         <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']/*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']/*[local-name()='CustomerPart']/*[local-name()='Attributes'] /*[local-name()='Description']" />
                      </partDescription>
                    </partDetail>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </root>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Current sample Output Shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.dataprint.com/global/3.0/rest/">
   <results>
      <partDetail>
         <partNumber>31500SB2100M</partNumber>
         <partDescription>PAD SET, RR.</partDescription>
      </partDetail>
   </results>
   <results>
      <partDetail>
         <partNumber>31500SB2100M</partNumber>
         <partDescription>PAD SET, RR.</partDescription>
      </partDetail>
   </results>
</root>
```

My Desired Output shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.dataprint.com/global/3.0/rest/">
   <results>         
      <partDetail>
         <partNumber>31500SB2100M</partNumber>
         <partDescription>PAD SET, RR.</partDescription>
      </partDetail>
   </results>
   <results>
      <partDetail>
         <partNumber>60211T7J305ZZ</partNumber>
         <partDescription>Kite  SET, RR.</partDescription>
      </partDetail>
   </results>
</root>
```

I'm trying to loop element  " a:CustomerPart"  to print PartNumber and b:Descriptionas Output but first a:CustomerPart data is getting repeated Twice.I Undestand there is code change is required,please help on this. 
Eiríkr Útlendi your patience/suggestions is much appreciated

Comment: 1) What do you want the output to look like?  Show us with some sample code.  2) Your "XSLT Applied" is invalid markup.  You have an opening `xsl:variable` tag, and then a closing `xsl:for-each` tag.  This is broken.  3) Assuming correct markup, `xsl:variable` only defines an immutable (unchange-able) variable value.  It doesn't "do" anything, it just grabs a piece of data and assigns it to that variable name.  So your XSLT won't do anything at all.

Comment: pls help with xslt code for generating below output- reading  PartNumber and Description elements from SOAP XML
    <root xmlns="dataprint.com/global/3.0/rest"> <results> <partDetail> <partNumber>31500SB2100M</partNumber> <partDescription>PAD SET, RR.</partDescription> </partDetail> </results> <results> <partDetail> <partNumber>60211T7J305ZZ</partNumber> <partDescription>Kite  SET, RR.</partDescription> </partDetail> </results> </root>

Comment: Your comment is nearly illegible -- comments do not preserve newlines or indentation.  Please **edit your post** to include: 1) your sample input, 2) your XSLT code, 3) your current sample output, and 4) your desired sample output.  Please also read about [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks Eiríkr Útlendi  for your  patience and Suggestions !!. I have edited my Post.Please check and provide solution.

Comment: Glad it's helpful.  :)  Your XSLT code sample, as written, starts from `<root>`, and thus it won't do anything, since XSLT engines process based on the instructions in `<xsl:template>`.  To understand your code, I'd need to see at least from `<xsl:template match=...>`

Comment: Eiríkr Útle, as asked I have added code which starts from <xsl:template Match/Stylesheet tag.Please go through my code and provide solution.Your advise is much Appreciated

Comment: Eiríkr Útle can you pls help on this

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `xsl:for-each`, the selected `CustomerPart` item becomes the context item. You should then select children/descendants of this `CustomerPart` using a relative path starting at this context item, not an absolute path starting at the root of the document (`/`).

That is, you should replace

```
    <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']
        /*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResponse']
        /*[local-name()='PullCustomerPartsPricingResult']
        /*[local-name()='CustomerPart']
        /*[local-name()='Attributes']
        /*[local-name()='PartNumber']" />
```

by

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='Attributes'] /*[local-name()='PartNumber']" />
```

or better, by

```
<xsl:value-of select="*:Attributes/*:PartNumber" />
```

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay for your timely reply

Comment: The protocol on StackOverflow is to tick the check-mark next to the question to mark an answer as accepted; comments saying "thanks" are then unnecessary.